# How to get current User Name of Windows in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I need to get the User Name of current Windows Login user. is there any way to do that in silverlight?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Windows Authentification and asp.net page as host?

So deny anonymous users

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

and use this code:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
...
    <param name="initParams" value="username=<%= User.Identity.Name %>" />
...
</object>
```

After that parse input params in the silverlight application:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var username = e.InitParams["username"];
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
```

Also I know another way to achieve this (with wcf service), but it is more complicated.

Comment: i very sorry i confused you.What i need is the user name you login your windows system